# Change MAMP PRO Path to Configuration File

Tags: mamp

I am running MAMP PRO 2.1.1 on a MAC using OS 10.7.4 (Lion).  How do I change the path to the configuration (php.ini) file so that it is the same as the path to the installed Configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

The path to the `php.ini` used will be based on the version of PHP you have selected in MAMP.  For example, with PHP 5.3.4 that would normally be:

```
/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.4.3/php.ini
```

Assuming you haven't changed the defaults, you should be also be able to visit the MAMP info page:

```
http://localhost:8888/MAMP/
```

Select the "phpInfo" tab and look for the "Loaded Configuration File" setting.